# App Crashing on Simulator and Device but not when Profiling

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, instruments

The app crashing with signal `SIGABRT` (the debugger output is `child already added. It can't be added again`) in the simulator and on the device. Runs fine when I profile the app in Xcode while running it on the simulator or the device. Why is this?

Update: I've figured out that this line of code is causing the problem:

```
Mover *moverObject = [[[Mover alloc] init] autorelease];
NSMutableArray * array = [moverObject moveToward:startPoint :finalPoint]//<-- This is the problem
```

`moveToward` is method that returns a `NSMutableArray` containing the points from the `startPoint` to the `finalPoint`. This worked fine early today but after I started testing something new I guess I broke it. I made no changes in the actual `Mover.h/.m` just in the `GameLayer.m` (where I was adding code). I'm not sure what I added to cause the problem.

Update 2: I did some more digging using breakpoints and I found that

```
GameLayer *gameLayerObject = [[GameLayer alloc] init];<-- This causes the crash
```

Inside `mover.m` where the method `moveToward::` is, this is the furthest it will go without crashing. Again the error is `child already added. It can't be added again.` Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

This may just be coincidence. Hard to say because you didn't post any code.

The error message is clear though: you're trying to `addChild` the same node more than once, either to the same parent or to a different parent. Check your code for situations where this can occur.

Comment: Yes I've been looking for where this could be happening, is there a profiler that you know of that could help with this? But why would the app working while I am profiling it? wouldn't the `SIGAGRT` cause it to crash while profiling as well?

Comment: Profiling means to analyze how your program runs, you mean debugging. If you haven't already, enable global exceptions breakpoint in Xcode. I can't tell why it works during profiling, perhaps you're simply not triggering the code that causes the bug.

Comment: Updated my question. And after it crashed on the device and simulator, I tried reproducing the crash while profiling, following the EXACT same steps but the app doesn't crash.